# Mail messages are stuck in outgoing queue in IIS SMTP server with windows authentication?

Tags: smtp, windows-authentication, windows-server-2012-r2, mail-server

I have installed Microsoft SMTP server in IIS of Windows Server 2012. When i have given Windows Integrated Security in Outbound security. The mail messages are stuck in outgoing queue of smtp server (in C:\inetpub\mailroot\Queue).

If i use anonymous authentication or basic authentication, the mail server is just working fine.

Anyone suggest what could be the possible reason for this?